# Best way to store a lot of data with timestamp in MySQL

Tags: mysql, algorithm

what I should do?

Imagine tennis match.

Operator pushing buttons (actions) "Ace", "Fault", "Winner", "Unforced error" etc
We have a lot of operators, matches at the same time. And we have a lot of requests to db from users (~1000 per min).

What is the best way to store match_id, player, action, time_of_action?

1) table with 1 row for every match: match_id, actions. Actions, players,timestamp coded into 1 string `#of player TINYINT id of action CHAR timestamp TIMESTAMP`

example: actions = "1A2014-11-28 09:01:21 2W2014-11-28 09:01:33 1F2014-11-28 09:01:49"

2) table with multiple rows for one match: id, match_id, player, action_id, current timestamp (id PRIMARY KEY)
its will be about 250K rows after one day (300 per match * 40 matches in 1 tournament * 20 tournaments per day)

what is better: a lot of rows and a lot of requests SELECT player, action_id, timestamp FROM scores WHERE match_id = N
or
same number of requests, less rows ( /300 ) but much bigger data in rows?

sry for my ugly language, I hope you understand me, if not, tell me

add: 
Im going to use it for match statistics on live or after match. 
Users open page Statistics of match Federer - Nadal and every 10-30 seconds page refreshing
Example: http://www.wimbledon.com/en_GB/slamtracker/slamtracker.html?ts=1419259452680&ref=www.wimbledon.com/en_GB/slamtracker/index.html&syn=none&

Comment: A primary consideration in how your store data is how you are going to use it.  WIthout that information, there is no guidance on what is "best".

Comment: Im going to use it for match statistics on live or after match. Users open page Statistics of match Federer - Nadal and every 10-30 seconds page refreshing Example: http://www.wimbledon.com/en_GB/slamtracker/slamtracker.html?ts=1419259452680&ref=www.wimbledon.com/en_GB/slamtracker/index.html&syn=none&

Comment: Ollie you are the best!

p.s. When I post similar questions on russian forums, a lot of "professionals" wrote to me that Im very stupid, idiot, newbie and how good are they. But nobody post answers. 

You guys always write right what I want to known. Very informative. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you create reference tables called

```
 match    match_id, name, venue          A row for each distinct match
 player   player_id, name                A row for each distinct player 
 action   action_id, name                This is a codelist  1=Ace  2=Fault, etc.
```

These tables will be relatively static.

Then, I suggest you create an event table containing the following items in the following order.

```
match_id
ts            (TIMESTAMP)
action_id
player_id
```

You should include all four of these columns in a composite primary key, in the order I have shown them.

Every time your scorers record an action you'll insert a new row to this table.

When you want to display the actions for a particular match, you can do this:

```
SELECT event.ts,
       action.name AS action,
       player.name AS player
  FROM event
  JOIN player ON event.player_id = player.player_id
  JOIN action ON event.action_id = action.action_id
 WHERE event.match_id = <<whatever match ID>> 
 ORDER BY event.match_id, event.ts
```

Because of the order of columns in the composite primary key on the `event` table, this kind of query will be very efficient even when you're inserting lots of new rows to that table.

MySQL is made for this kind of application.  Still, when your site begins to receive tons of user traffic, you probably should arrange to run these queries just once every few seconds, cache the results, and use the cached results to send information to your users.

If you want to retrieve the match IDs for all the matches presently active (that is, with an event within the last ten minutes) you can do this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT match.id, match.name, match.venue
  FROM event
  JOIN match on event.match_id = match.match_id
 WHERE event.ts >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
```

If you need to do this sort of query a lot, I suggest you create an extra index on `(ts, match_id)`.